# How can I speed up a query that uses subqueries in the SELECT to calculate values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that looks up information for a given patient and then calculates some more info based on data from some related tables. Some of the calculated fields are related to the same items. For example, "l_purchase_date" and "l_data" are both referencing the same entry in the database. The query is working, but it is incredibly slow. I am sure there must be some faster way to do this.

```
SELECT p.id AS 'patient_id', p.first_name AS 'f_name', p.last_name AS 'l_name', p.date_of_birth AS 'dob', p.email AS 'email_address', p.street1 AS 'street1', p.street2 AS 'street2', p.street3 AS 'street3', p.city AS 'city', p.[state] AS 'state', p.zip AS 'zip1',
        p.phone1 AS 'primary_phone',
        CASE
            WHEN p.phone1_type = 'cell' THEN p.phone1
            WHEN p.phone2_type = 'cell' THEN p.phone2
            WHEN p.phone3_type = 'cell' THEN p.phone3
            WHEN p.phone4_type = 'cell' THEN p.phone4
            ELSE NULL
        END AS 'mobile_phone',
        'test_date' = (SELECT MAX(test_date)
                       FROM tbl_appointment sa
                           JOIN tbl_hearing_test t ON sa.id = t.appt_id
                       WHERE sa.patient_id = p.id AND t.test_date <= GETDATE()),
        'l_purchase_date' = (SELECT TOP(1) sili.[date]
                             FROM tbl_invoice_line_items sili
                                 JOIN tbl_invoices si ON si.id = sili.invoice_id
                             WHERE si.patient_id = p.id AND sili.[type] = 'hearing_aid' AND sili.side = 'left' AND sili.date <= GETDATE()
                             ORDER BY sili.[date] DESC),
        'r_purchase_date' = (SELECT TOP(1) sili.[date]
                             FROM tbl_invoice_line_items sili
                                 JOIN tbl_invoices si ON si.id = sili.invoice_id
                             WHERE si.patient_id = p.id AND sili.[type] = 'hearing_aid' AND sili.side = 'right' AND sili.date <= GETDATE()
                             ORDER BY sili.[date] DESC),
        'l_data' = (SELECT TOP(1) sili.[data]
                    FROM tbl_invoice_line_items sili
                        JOIN tbl_invoices si ON si.id = sili.invoice_id
                    WHERE si.patient_id = p.id AND sili.[type] = 'hearing_aid' AND sili.side = 'left' AND sili.date <= GETDATE()
                    ORDER BY sili.[date] DESC),
        'r_data' = (SELECT TOP(1) sili.[data]
                    FROM tbl_invoice_line_items sili
                        JOIN tbl_invoices si ON si.id = sili.invoice_id
                    WHERE si.patient_id = p.id AND sili.[type] = 'hearing_aid' AND sili.side = 'right' AND sili.date <= GETDATE()
                    ORDER BY sili.[date] DESC),
        p.phone_status AS 'call_status', p.mail_status, p.text_status, p.email_status, p.[type],
        'max_purchase_date' = (SELECT MAX(sili.[date])
                               FROM tbl_invoice_line_items sili
                                   JOIN tbl_invoices si ON si.id = sili.invoice_id
                               WHERE si.patient_id = p.id AND sili.[date] <= GETDATE()),
        'last_appt_date' = (SELECT TOP(1) sa.[date]
                            FROM tbl_appointment sa
                            WHERE sa.patient_id = p.id AND sa.[date] <= GETDATE()
                            ORDER BY sa.[date] DESC),
        'last_appt_status' = (SELECT TOP(1) sa.[status]
                              FROM tbl_appointment sa
                              WHERE sa.patient_id = p.id AND sa.[date] <= GETDATE()
                              ORDER BY sa.[date] DESC),
        'last_appt_type' = (SELECT TOP(1) sa.[type]
                            FROM tbl_appointment sa
                            WHERE sa.patient_id = p.id AND sa.[date] <= GETDATE()
                            ORDER BY sa.[date] DESC),
        'next_appt_date' = (SELECT TOP(1) sa.[date]
                            FROM tbl_appointment sa
                            WHERE sa.patient_id = p.id AND sa.[date] > GETDATE()
                            ORDER BY sa.[date]),
        'next_appt_status' = (SELECT TOP(1) sa.[status]
                              FROM tbl_appointment sa
                              WHERE sa.patient_id = p.id AND sa.[date] > GETDATE()
                              ORDER BY sa.[date]),
        'next_appt_type' = (SELECT TOP(1) sa.[type]
                            FROM tbl_appointment sa
                            WHERE sa.patient_id = p.id AND sa.[date] > GETDATE()
                            ORDER BY sa.[date])
    FROM tbl_patient p
    GROUP BY p.id, p.first_name, p.last_name, p.date_of_birth, p.email, p.street1, p.street2, p.street3, p.city, p.[state], p.zip, p.phone1, p.phone1_type, p.phone2, p.phone2_type, p.phone3, p.phone3_type, p.phone4, p.phone4_type, p.phone_status, p.mail_status, p.text_status, p.email_status, p.[type]
```

Related items:

- l_purchase_date/l_data
- r_purchase_date/r_data
- last_appt_date/last_appt_status/last_appt_type
- next_appt_date/next_appt_status/next_appt_type

If I can combine the query fields in each of these rows into a single lookup, I think it will speed this query up by quite a bit. Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: You might want to consider simplifying the question to the shortest representative and reproducible example.

Comment: You say this is for a given patient, but you’re executing the subqueries for every row in your patient table. Are you missing a filter? If you need to do this for every row every time you run this query then you would probably benefit from unnestting these subqueries so that you can use bulk friendly operations like scans and hash joins

Comment: Can you post a copy of the actual query plan for this query? If you don't know how how to do this, use this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2):

I would consider building a temporary table to gather some of the necessary data.. it looks like you're using a lot of the same data in each of your subqueries. Build a temp table to gather that data then join to the temp table instead of multiple subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

For all of the tables in the subqueries try indexes on `(patient_id, date, <the column you actually SELECT>)` or `(patient_id, type, date, <the column you actually SELECT>)` for those who have the `type` column (or if I missed some that also have other columns involved in the `WHERE` clause of the respective subquery an index on `(patient_id, <the other columns in the WHERE clause>, date, <the column you actually select>)` for those -- you get the pattern).

If a table appears more than once in several sub queries, you can also try to include all the `SELECT`ed columns in the index, like `(patient_id, date, <all the columns you actually SELECT>)`. But that might ultimately be too large for the optimizer to consider. If it even gets that this could be used to answer multiple sub queries at once that is.

Alternatively you can also try to just cover the `WHERE` clause (and possibly, the `ORDER BY`) like on `(patient_id, date)` or analog if there are other columns in the `WHERE` clause.

Depending on the direction of `ORDER BY date` you might also try to use an index per direction, like on `(patient_id, date ASC)` and on `(patient_id, date DESC)` (and again analog for other columns in the `WHERE` clause).

If that doesn't do it, you might also try to `OUTER APPLY` a derived table for all of the tables in the subqueries. But, if a table appears multiple times in the subqueries with the same `WHERE` clause in each, just `OUTER APPLY` it once. I won't write that all for you so the following just covers a small portion of your query to demonstrate the pattern:

```
SELECT p.id patient_id,
       x.[date] last_appt_date,
       x.[status] last_appt_status,
       x.[type] sa.last_appt_type
       FROM tbl_patient p
            OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1
                                sa.[date],
                                sa.[status],
                                sa.[type]
                                FROM tbl_appointment sa
                                     WHERE sa.patient_id = p.id
                                           AND sa.[date] <= GETDATE()
                                ORDER BY sa.[date] DESC) x;
```

Here you might either try an index on `(patient_id, date, <all the columns you actually SELECT>)` or just covering the `WHERE` clause and the `ORDER BY`, e.g. on `(patient_id, date)` (and again analog for other columns in the `WHERE` clause and possibly for each `ORDER BY` direction).

Experiment to find out what gives you the best plan.

And stop using single quotes around aliases. Single quotes are for string (and date, etc.) literals. Use `[]` if you must quote them or just nothing otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The approach here will depend on what the actual execution plan is for this query. Here's how to get the [actual plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver15). It's essential to have these when debugging these sorts of problems.

Looking at the query is that what might be running slow is is contained in the subqueries:

```
SELECT TOP(1) sili.[data]
                    FROM tbl_invoice_line_items sili
                        JOIN tbl_invoices si ON si.id = sili.invoice_id
                    WHERE si.patient_id = p.id AND sili.[type] = 'hearing_aid' AND sili.side = 'right' AND sili.date <= GETDATE()
                    ORDER BY sili.[date] DESC
```

The way this query could end up being executed is that it does scan/seek on tbl_invoice_line_items first for 'hearing aid' before joining this against the invoices where it can find the joined invoices for the patient. This would read a large chunk of the table only to throw almost all of it away. And you do this many times within the query.

I'd know for sure if I could see the plan for the query - but given the information presented that's where I'd start.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible option for you.  Since you are getting all records from the patient table, and there will only be a single patient ID, you don't need to do a group-by in the query.  By having the secondary sub-selects each returning a maximum of one-row-per set, you will not get a Cartesian result, hence no need for GROUP BY clause.

What I did was to perform two pre-queries, one on the patients appointments to pre-get most recent and next available, then re-joined back to the underlying apointment tables to get additional details.  Similarly for the invoices for most recent purchase, in addition to most recent associated with left/right hearing aide items.

Now, this could be even more simplified IF (and big if), the underlying tables such as for invoices, the invoice ID is always sequentially created based on the date.  Ex: Invoice ID 1234  on Dec 15, 2020 would never have invoice ID 1235 Prior to Dec 15, 2020.  In other words, the invoice date and internal IDs are auto-increment.  If so, I can revise the query.

```
SELECT 
        p.id patient_id, 
        p.first_name f_name, 
        p.last_name l_name, 
        p.date_of_birth dob, 
        p.email email_address, 
        p.street1, 
        p.street2, 
        p.street3, 
        p.city, 
        p.state, 
        p.zip zip1,
        p.phone1 primary_phone,
        CASE
            WHEN p.phone1_type = 'cell' THEN p.phone1
            WHEN p.phone2_type = 'cell' THEN p.phone2
            WHEN p.phone3_type = 'cell' THEN p.phone3
            WHEN p.phone4_type = 'cell' THEN p.phone4
            ELSE NULL
        END mobile_phone,
        p.phone_status call_status, 
        p.mail_status, 
        p.text_status, 
        p.email_status, 
        p.type,

        -- now from the pre-query per patient on exams for hearing and most recent and next appointments
        coalesce( AptPerPerson.MaxHearingTest, '' ) test_date,

        coalesce( priorApp.date, '' ) last_appt_date,
        coalesce( priorApp.status, '' ) last_appt_status,
        coalesce( priorApp.type, '' ) last_appt_type,

        coalesce( nextAppt.date, '' ) next_appt_date,
        coalesce( nextAppt.status, '' ) next_appt_status,
        coalesce( nextAppt.type, '' ) next_appt_type,

        -- from the pre-query per patient from invoices and line items
        inv.maxPurchaseDate max_purchase_date,
        coalesce( inv.MaxLeftAidDate, '' ) l_purchase_date,
        coalesce( inv.MaxRightAidDate, '' ) r_purchase_date,

        -- and any possible corresponding line items for hearing aide left/right
        LeftDtl.data l_data,
        RightDtl.data r_data
    FROM 
        tbl_patient p
            -- this query will get the most recent and the next future appointment for all patients
            -- then this can be joined to the appointment table directly / respectively vs the 
            -- 6 column-based queries in the original. 
            LEFT JOIN
            ( select
                    app.patient_id,
                    max( case when app.date <= getdate() then app.date else null end ) MaxAppntBeforeNow,
                    min( case when app.date > getdate() then app.date else null end ) NextApptDate,
                    max( case when ht.test_date <= getdate() then ht.test_date else null end ) MaxHearingTest,
                FROM 
                    tbl_appointment app
                        LEFT JOIN tbl_hearing_test ht
                            on app.id = ht.appt_id
                group by 
                    app_patientID ) AptPerPerson
                on p.id = AptPerPerson.patient_id

                -- re-join on the one record per person to max appointments already had
                LEFT JOIN tbl_appointment priorApp
                    on AptPerPerson.patient_id = priorApp.patient_id
                    AND AptPerPerson.MaxAppntBeforeNow = priorApp.date 

                -- and again for future appointments
                LEFT JOIN tbl_appointment nextAppt
                    on AptPerPerson.patient_id = nextAppt.patient_id
                    AND AptPerPerson.NextApptDate = nextAppt.date


            -- similarly, pre-query invoice line items per patient basis
            LEFT JOIN
            ( select
                    si.patient_id,
                    max( sili.date ) maxPurchaseDate,
                    max( case when sili.type = 'hearing_aid' and sili.side = 'left' then sili.date else null end ) MaxLeftAidDate,
                    max( case when sili.type = 'hearing_aid' and sili.side = 'right' then sili.date else null end ) MaxRightAidDate,
                from
                    tbl_invoices si 
                        JOIN tbl_invoice_line_items sili
                            ON si.id = sili.invoice_id
                            AND sili.date <= getdate()
                group by
                    si.patient_id ) inv

                    -- now, getting left-side hearing aid detail via join
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_invoices siLeft
                        ON inv.patient_id = siLeft.patient_id
                            LEFT JOIN tbl_invoice_line_items LeftDtl
                                ON siLeft.id = LeftDtl.invoice_id
                                and inv.MaxLeftAidDate = LeftDtl.date
                                AND LeftDtl.type = 'hearing_aid'
                                AND LeftDtl.side = 'left'

                    -- now right-side hearing aid
                    LEFT JOIN tbl_invoices siRight
                        ON inv.patient_id = siRight.patient_id
                            LEFT JOIN tbl_invoice_line_items RightDtl
                                ON siRight.id = RightDtl.invoice_id
                                and inv.MaxRighttAidDate = RightDtl.date
                                AND RightDtl.type = 'hearing_aid'
                                AND RightDtl.side = 'right'
```